# Find the distance from P to C

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

ABCD is a rectangular garden plot.P is a garden water tap.
Find the distance from the tap to corner C.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but I am almost blind ! Is $BD$ the diagonal with $P$ on it ?

Comment: Yes, BD is a diagonal with P on it.

Comment: @Claude: I don't think it's implied that DPB are collinear -- they may be, but such an assumption is not required to solve the problem.

Comment: @HenningMakholm. Since I am very very bad in geometry, I was just thinking about an algebraic approach (and this hypothesis makes the problem simpler). Thanks.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Ah yes! Now I see why why DPB need not be necessarily collinear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Draw perpendiculars from $P$ onto the sides of the rectangle. This splits $AB$ into segments of length $l$ and $r$, and $AD$ into segments of length $u$ and $d$. Now,

$$ r^2+d^2 = (l^2+d^2) + (r^2+u^2) - (l^2+u^2) $$

Comment: You mean split AB starting from A towards B in the lengths l and r respectively. And split AD starting from A towards D in the lengths u and d respectively?

Comment: @pirsquare: Well, would or wouldn't that way of dividing things make the hint useful?

Comment: Wanted to make sure the order you suggested is correct. But from your hint I see that the 3 lengths 5, 7 and 8 can be connected using the Pythagoras Theorem.

Comment: @pirsquare: Well, whether or not there's a typo in my hint is not something you need to worry about, as long as it does manage to convey enough inspiration for you to construct a typo-free solution yourself.

Comment: Yes, it does provide a big clue to a connection...am working it out.

Comment: Square root of 40! Got it! Many thanks!